# Where's the code for the predict() method for Ridge regression

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm looking to do some custom predictions using a model I built with Ridge regression. Essentially, I want to selectively zero out parts of the model to be able to determine how they contribute to the overall answer. For this, I need to understand how scikit-learn implements predictions from a model. I have been looking into the code, but I am not finding where the prediction is performed. Could someone give me a hint where I should be looking? Apologies in advance if I am missing something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting to see if this question would bear fruit, I decided to do some searching. Due to the disappointing limitations of the o/s and allowed software load on the computer I am using, I had to essentially write my own version of grep:

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

BASE_PATH = Path(r'C:\Users\mermaldad\Downloads\scikit'
                 r'-learn-main\scikit-learn-main')
pattern = 'class _BaseRidge' # in _ridge.py
pattern = 'class LinearModel' # in _base.py

result = list(BASE_PATH.rglob("*.[pP][yY]"))

for f in result:
    file = open(f, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    for line in file:
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            print(f'{f.stem}.py: {line}')
```

Using this tool, I figured out that class Ridge is a child to class _BaseRidge which is in turn a child to class LinearModel. LinearModel has a method predict().

Through this exercise, I imagine there are tools that would have helped map out these relationships. Suggestions are welcome.